# Ruby on Rails - Referencing a many_to_many relationship

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

So if I have a many_to_many table with just the ids in it, and I want to reference it within another model, how would I do that?

So in the model, which is called Rating, I want to say that it is linked to both of those things in the association, in this case Course and Textbook. So a Rating is defined by the Textbook and the Course. Should I add two id attributes to Rating that link to both? Should I add an ID to the many_to_many and then have an ID attribute in the Rating table? Or is there something else I can do?

**UPDATE:**

So here is my ERD so far. You can ignore things with Students and Professors.
[image: ERD]
On the right hand side the the table that I made according to @RichPeck. I'm confused on how to create the entries. Lets say for example I create a Course.

`course = Course.new(params)`

I then do this to make a Textbook.

`textbook = course.textbooks.build(params)`

Now when I do `course.textbooks`, it lists the textbook i just made but when I do `textbook.courses` I get an empty list. Also, after saving them and exiting the shell then reopening, both commands reutnr empty list. Now this is because the join table, CourseTextboks, is empty. Why is rails not adding an entry into there? Do I need to do something special?

Here are the relevant files:

CreateCourseTextbooksMigration

```
class CreateCourseTextbooks < ActiveRecord::Migration
  def change
    create_table :course_textbooks do |t|
      t.references :course, index: true
      t.references :textbook, index: true

      t.timestamps
    end
  end
end
```

CreateTextbookMigration

```
class CreateTextbooks < ActiveRecord::Migration
  def change
    create_table :textbooks do |t|
      t.string :title
      t.string :authors
      t.string :edition
      t.float :price
      t.string :isbn
      t.text :description
      t.string :image_url
      t.date :published

      t.timestamps
    end
  end
end
```

CreateCourseMigration

```
class CreateCourses < ActiveRecord::Migration
  def change
    create_table :courses do |t|
      t.string :title
      t.string :letters
      t.integer :number

      t.timestamps
    end
  end
end
```

And the models:

Course

```
class Course < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_many :student_courses
  has_many :students, through: :student_courses

  has_many :professor_courses
  has_many :professors, through: :professor_courses

  has_many :textbook_courses
  has_many :textbooks, through: :textbook_courses

  validates_presence_of :title, :letters, :number
end
```

Textbook

```
class Textbook < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_many :textbook_courses
  has_many :courses, through: :textbook_courses
end
```

CourseTextbook

```
class CourseTextbook < ActiveRecord::Base
  belongs_to :course
  belongs_to :textbook

  has_many :rating_course_textbooks, :class_name => "RatingCourseTextbook" 
  has_many :ratings, :through => :rating_course_textbooks

  validates_presence_of :course
end
```

Can you help me out, guys?

**UPDATE2:**

I figured it out after about a half hour of searching and paying more attention to the SQL generated when creating objects.. So when you do a `course.build` it just returns the object and somehow links it, but not through join table. I found out that you have to save the course NOT the new professor, or just use create.

This is what was happening

```
>>> course = Course.create(params)
    # INSERT into courses table
>>> professor = course.build(params)

>>> professor.save
    # INSERT into professors table
>>> course.professors
    # [Professor {id:1, blah}]
>>> professor.courses
    # []
```

And this is what works now

```
>>> course = Course.create(params)
    # INSERT into courses table
>>> professor = course.build(params)

>>> course.save
    # INSERT into professors table
    # INSERT into professor_courses table
>>> course.professors
    # [Professor {id:1, blah}]
>>> professor.courses
    # [Course {id:1, blah}]
```

YAY! Now just to see if it all works with my other models, like the RatingsCourseTextbooks

**UPDATE3**
So after messing around for a little while, I discovered that I was making it too complicated. A rating can only have one CourseTextbook so I didn't need another join table. I just added a CourseTextbook ID to Rating.

[image: New ERD]

Thanks for your support

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I'm guessing you're new to Rails, so I'll explain how this would work for you here:

---

**[ActiveRecord Associations](http://guides.rubyonrails.org/association_basics.html)**

One of Rails' core features is the ActiveRecord association

ActiveRecord brings the relational database schema to life, allowing you to reference different "related" models from a single query. It's how you can call `@user.images` etc

ActiveRecord sits above the database layer, and is referenced by your models using the `has_many`, `belongs_to`, etc references. If you want to reference your related models, you'll have to use these, like this:

```
#app/models/user.rb
Class User < ActiveRecord::Base
    has_many :images
end 

#app/models/image.rb
Class Image < ActiveRecord::Base
    belongs_to :user
end
```

---

**Your Code**

Seems you're using `has-and-belongs-to-many`

As mentioned by Sachin Singh, you'll likely be best using a [`polymorphic` relationship](http://guides.rubyonrails.org/association_basics.html#polymorphic-associations) with these models:
[image: Polymorphic Association]

This allows you to reference the relationship from multiple models, with Rails / ActiveRecord populating the polymorphic fields with the model name & id. Here's how your models may look:

```
Class Rating < ActiveRecord::Base
    belongs_to :rateable, :polymorphic => true
end

Class Course < ActiveRecord::Base
    has_many :ratings, :as => :rateable
end

Class Textbook < ActiveRecord::Base
   has_many :ratings, :as => :rateable
end
```

---

**Update**

If you wanted to have specific textbooks for certain courses, and have ratings for those textbooks, you'll probably best use `has_many :through`

This might be completely off the mark, but I'd set up the `courses` and `textbooks` tables as "top-level" tables, and then have `textbook_courses` as a join-model. I'd then have `textbook_course_ratings` as another join model to give the required ratings per textbook

The goal will be `@course.textbooks.ratings`

```
Class Course < ActiveRecord::Base
    has_many :textbook_courses
    has_many :textbooks, :through => :textbook_courses
end

Class Textbook < ActiveRecord::Base
   has_many :textbook_courses
   has_many :courses, :through :textbook_courses
end

Class TextbookCourse < ActiveRecord::Base
   belongs_to :textbook
   belongs_to :course

   has_many :textbook_course_ratings, :class_name => "TextbookCourseRating" 
   has_many :ratings, :through => :textbook_course_ratings
end
```

---

```
Class TextbookCourseRating < ActiveRecord::Base
    belongs_to :textbook_course
    belongs_to :rating
end

Class Rating < ActiveRecord::Base
    has_many :textbook_course_ratings, :class_name => "TextbookCourseRating"
    has_many :textbooks, :through => :textbook_ratings
end
```

I've never done such a deep `has_many :through` relationship before; but it should work

There several important things to note:

1. You'll have to change your join tables to include a `primary key` (id) - HABTM doesn't need them, but HMT does
2. You'll have a lot of `accepts_nested_attributes_for` to do :)

Your join tables for this would look like:

```
textbook_courses
id | course_id | textbook_id | created_at | updated_at

textbook_courses_ratings
id | textbook_course_id | rating_id | created_at | updated_at
```

Comment: This is a very good explanation of polymorphic relationships and I appreciate that because it's valuable knowledge but I believe you either misunderstood or I communicated poorly but what I want is there to be a rating for a textbook for each course the textbook is in. Not that I want ratings for both a textbook AND a course. I'm not rating the courses.

Comment: You could use `has_many :through` for that from what you've posted - let me write it up for you!

Comment: Posted update - it would be great to hear your thoughts

Comment: Thanks dude. I think that's what I want. So I'm going to add an id to the textbook_courses table, huh? I'll try implementing this and I'll get back with you

Comment: @RichPeck So what is the 'accepts_nested_attributes_for' for?

Answer (score 0):

if, A Course and TextBook has many ratings, then ratings table should be polymorphic.

```
class Rating < AcrtiveRecord::Base    
  belongs_to :ratable, polymorphic: true    
end

class Course < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_many :ratings, as: :ratable
end

class TextBook < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_many :ratings, as: :ratable
end
```

ratings table will have two column named ratable_type and ratable_id

ratable_type : it will hold class name Course or Textbook.

ratable_id : it will hold id of associated abject.

Comment: It's not that a reading belongs to a course OR a textbook. It's both at once. So there could be different ratings for the same textbook in a different course